# Regular expression match for multple line s in python

Tags: python, regex

I am a new python user. Writing some codes to match a multiline scenario with regular expression. But could not get the answer. Can anyone help me please if I am missing something.

I tried in `pythex.org` and it is matching the desired two lines.But when I am trying from a code

```
a = """
 MEG        Type     EntityId Level PrimVlan CC Inter(ms) CC Priority CC EnaStatus
---------- -------- -------- ----- -------- ------------ ----------- ------------
meg401     lsp      1        4     3        3.3          6           enable

MEP ID     Type     EntityId Level Intf    RMEP ID  Direction Active Status
---------- -------- -------- ----- ------- -------- --------- -------------
meg401        lsp      1        4     0/5     451      down      disable
"""

result = re.match("meg401(.*)",a,re.M)

print result
```

It is failing. Appreciate any suggestions on this!

Comment: what you want to match ?

Comment: I think you want to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.

Use `search` instead

```
result = re.search("meg401(.*)",a,re.M)
```

As a **suggestion**, as you have more than 1 matching value use `findall`

```
result = re.findall("meg401(.*)",a,re.M)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = re.findall("meg401(.*)",a,re.M)
```

Use `re.findall` and not `re.match`.

`re.match` matches the beginning of a string.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/7#python